# Is it possible to fire .live() when objects enters DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Now I'm doing it this way:

```
$('div.myDiv').live('mouseenter',function() {    }
```

This is the only way I found to be sure that code gets loaded before using the node. But it would be nicer if function fired when object enters DOM tree.

Comment: What would be "nicer" about that?

Comment: so, when are the objects being added to the dom?  on mouse enter of myDiv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DOMNodeInserted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM_Events#DOMNodeInserted) event on the container elements where you new elements will be added.

Comment: If you scroll down just a tiny bit, a big red box says it's deprecated. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [**livequery**](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) plugin provides that functionality:

```
$('div.myDiv').livequery(function() {
    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        alert("!");
    }).mouseenter();
});
```

Or if you want to do something *only* when the element is created:

```
$('div.myDiv').livequery(function() { alert("!"); });
```

Here's a [blog post showing how it works](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-create-event/).

And here's a [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/bFwUj/)